# Odbc connection not working if not defined as DSN entry

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc

I have a problem with installing ODBC driver under Windows (7, 64bit) to connect to Oracle database. They kind of work - I mean I can define a DSN entry and open connection using "DSN=foobar" connection string but I can't use something more generic like passing full connection string to OdbcConnection or basing it on tnsnames.ora file. In both cases I get

"Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Answer (score 0):

What client software are you using? The answer is probably going to be, use ADO

Comment: For the purpose of this quetsion you can assume I'm writing simple console .NET application using System.Data.Odbc. I'd like to stick with ODBC.

Comment: If you're asking about which client version - it is Oracle Database Client for Oracle 11.2